# Smarty кэширование динамического элемента

Tags: smarty, кэширование

Шаблонизатор Smarty. Есть шаблон, одинаковый для определенного раздела страниц, за исключением динамической части, данные которой получаются из бд. 
Если его включить в кеш, то данные из бд не будут меняться при переходе на следующий материал такого же раздела (шаблона). Если исключить динамическую часть с помощью тегов `{nocache}`, то запросы к бд для получения динамической части будут выполняться при каждом входе на один и тот же материал.

Вопрос: как включить кеширование статической части шаблона, а вызов динамической выполнять только один раз, а затем кешировать её.

p.s Использование `cache_id` не подходит (так как кеширует каждый раз заново статические элементы шаблона, теряется сам смысл кеша для страниц, которые посещаются 1 раз)

Comment: Хм, странно, что упустил из документации, что `cache_id` можно назначить для `include`. Сейчас закину динамическую часть в отдельные шаблоны и включу их в статические с помощью `include` c `cache id`. Должно работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мое решение:

Оставляем в оригинальном шаблоне только статическую часть. Динамическую размещаем в отдельном шаблоне. Делаем `include` с присвоенным `cache_id`.

Итог: Статическая часть подгружается только один раз. Динамическая часть тоже только один раз. Все последующие разы берется начальный статический шаблон и динамическая часть по id, если ее нет, то она создается.

В бекенде задать проверку `is_cached` перед выполнением запроса к бд.